# javascript change background and play sound with one button

Tags: javascript, events, audio, setinterval, addeventlistener

I'm building a clock inspired from the link below with added features like the single party button will play a music and change the BodyBGcolor per second.

https://codepen.io/codifiedconcepts/pen/bwgxRq

The music plays and pauses fine, but the BG starts changing but doesn't stop if I click to pause, and starts flickering and gets faster if I click the button again.

```
var partyTime = false;
var catMusic = new Audio("media/party.mp3");

function partyEvent() {
// partyTime and catMusic are defined outside
// otherwise they get re-defined without changing the old definition
 if (partyTime === false) {
  partyTime = true;
  catMusic.play();
  partyBtn.innerHTML = "PARTY OVER";
} else {
  partyTime = false;
  catMusic.pause();
  partyBtn.innerHTML = "PARTY TIME";
 }
}

var i = 0;
function changeBG() {
var color = ["red", "blue", "brown", "green"];
document.body.style.backgroundColor = color[i];
i = (i + 1) % color.length;

 if (partyTime === true) {
  var initBG = setInterval(changeBG, 1000);
} else {
  clearInterval(initBG);
}
}
```

I have another function which changes the BGcolor 5 times in a day, for morning, noon, evening etc.. as a switch statement, I'm showing one case here..

```
switch (true) {
case hour <= 5:
  imgTxt.innerHTML = "GET SOME SLEEPZ BRO";
  catImg.style.background = "url('img/earlyMorning.jpg')";
  catImg.style.backgroundSize = "cover";
  document.body.style.backgroundColor= "#2d3037";
  clockBody.style.color = "#99ffcc";
  break;
```

please help this noob, and sorry for the indentation, it gets all same after pasting here..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (partyTime === true) {
    var initBG = setInterval(changeBG, 1000);
} else {
    clearInterval(initBG);
}
```

Here you are creating initBG local to `if` block. In the `else` block `initBG` is undefined so it does not stop the `interval` process.

Solution: Define `initBG` outside the `partyEvent` function.

```
var initBG;
if (partyTime === true) {
    initBG = setInterval(changeBG, 1000);
} else {
    clearInterval(initBG);
}
```

Comment: Yes, this fixed the problem. But initBG runs as page loads, how do I make it so it runs only when partyEvent() runs or when partyTime == true?

Comment: I tried it earlier, didn't work. Now it's working perfect, thanks a lot for this Mean Coder :)